# mysql_real_escape_string \\\ syntax

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I was reading online that turning off magic quotes is the easy answer to a lot of escapes characters being added in the database like:

Email: href="\"\"\\"\\\\"\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\

So I used a htaccess to turn off magic quotes: `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`

The issue is that it completely broke my web page, the divs are merged, things are totally broken.

I know it's been asked a lot on this forum but I can't get the syntax right, this is what I have used in my save.php

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $content1 = $_POST['content1']; //get posted data
    $content1 = mysql_real_escape_string($content1);    //escape string

                      $content2 = $_POST['content2']; //get posted data
    $content2 = mysql_real_escape_string($content2);    //escape string 

                      $content3 = $_POST['content3']; //get posted data
    $content3 = mysql_real_escape_string($content3);    //escape string

                      $content4 = $_POST['content4']; //get posted data
    $content4 = mysql_real_escape_string($content4);    //escape string

                      $content5 = $_POST['content5']; //get posted data
    $content5 = mysql_real_escape_string($content5);    //escape string

                      $content6 = $_POST['content6']; //get posted data
    $content6 = mysql_real_escape_string($content6);    //escape string

                       $content7 = $_POST['content7']; //get posted data
     $content7 = mysql_real_escape_string($content7);   //escape string

                      $content8 = $_POST['content8']; //get posted data
    $content8 = mysql_real_escape_string($content8);    //escape string

                      $content9 = $_POST['content9']; //get posted data
    $content9 = mysql_real_escape_string($content9);    //escape string

                      $content10 = $_POST['content10']; //get posted data
    $content10 = mysql_real_escape_string($content10);  //escape string

                      $content11 = $_POST['content11']; //get posted data
    $content11 = mysql_real_escape_string($content11);  //escape string

                      $content12 = $_POST['content12']; //get posted data
    $content12 = mysql_real_escape_string($content12);  //escape string

                      $content13 = $_POST['content13']; //get posted data
    $content13 = mysql_real_escape_string($content13);  //escape string

                      $content14 = $_POST['content14']; //get posted data
    $content14 = mysql_real_escape_string($content14);  //escape string

                      $content15 = $_POST['content15']; //get posted data
    $content15 = mysql_real_escape_string($content15);  //escape string

                      $content16 = $_POST['content16']; //get posted data
    $content16 = mysql_real_escape_string($content16);  //escape string

                      $content17 = $_POST['content17']; //get posted data
    $content17 = mysql_real_escape_string($content17);  //escape string

                      $content18 = $_POST['content18']; //get posted data
    $content18 = mysql_real_escape_string($content18);  //escape string

                      $content19 = $_POST['content19']; //get posted data
    $content19 = mysql_real_escape_string($content19);  //escape string

                      $content20 = $_POST['content20']; //get posted data
    $content20 = mysql_real_escape_string($content20);  //escape string

                      $content21 = $_POST['content21']; //get posted data
    $content21 = mysql_real_escape_string($content21);  //escape string

    $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content1' WHERE element_id = '1') ";
                        mysql_query($sql);
                      $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content2' WHERE element_id = '2') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);

                       $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content3' WHERE element_id = '3') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                      $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content4' WHERE element_id = '4') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                      $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content5' WHERE element_id = '5') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content6' WHERE element_id = '6') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content7' WHERE element_id = '7') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content8' WHERE element_id = '8') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content9' WHERE element_id = '9') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content10' WHERE element_id = '10') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content11' WHERE element_id = '11') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content12' WHERE element_id = '12') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content13' WHERE element_id = '13') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content14' WHERE element_id = '14') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content15' WHERE element_id = '15') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content16' WHERE element_id = '16') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content17' WHERE element_id = '17') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content18' WHERE element_id = '18') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content19' WHERE element_id = '19') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content20' WHERE element_id = '20') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
                         $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content21' WHERE element_id = '21') ";
                      mysql_query($sql);
```

------ UPDATE ----
Ok so I have scraped the above lengthy code, and this is what i am left in my save.php:

```
<?php
    include("db.php");


                      for ($i = 1; $i < 21; $i++) {
    $content = $_POST['content' . $i]; //get posted data
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  //escape string
    $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content' WHERE element_id = $i)";
    mysql_query($sql);
}

    if (mysql_query($sql))
    {
        echo 1;
    }

?>
```

However...It is not saving anymore, anyone can see a syntax error?

----- NEW UPDATE -----

Could it be that my ajax save.js needs updating?? Hence the Reason why I am getting an error save to DB, after I had updated the save.php with the "for" loop?
Please see below code for save.js

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {         
var content1 = $('.editable1').html();  
var content2 = $('.editable2').html(); 
var content3 = $('.editable3').html();  
var content4 = $('.editable4').html(); 
var content5 = $('.editable5').html(); 
var content6 = $('.editable6').html();  
var content7 = $('.editable7').html(); 
var content8 = $('.editable8').html();  
var content9 = $('.editable9').html(); 
var content10 = $('.editable10').html(); 
var content11 = $('.editable11').html();  
var content12 = $('.editable12').html(); 
var content13 = $('.editable13').html();  
var content14 = $('.editable14').html(); 
var content15 = $('.editable15').html(); 
var content16 = $('.editable16').html();  
var content17 = $('.editable17').html(); 
var content18 = $('.editable18').html();  
var content19 = $('.editable19').html(); 
var content20 = $('.editable20').html(); 
var content21 = $('.editable21').html();  


        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                                                                                    content1: content1, 
                                                                                    content2: content2,
                                                                                    content3: content3,
                                                                                    content4: content4,
                                                                                    content5: content5,
                                                                                     content6: content6, 
                                                                                    content7: content7,
                                                                                    content8: content8,
                                                                                    content9: content9,
                                                                                    content10: content10,
                                                                                     content11: content11, 
                                                                                    content12: content12,
                                                                                    content13: content13,
                                                                                    content14: content14,
                                                                                    content15: content15,
                                                                                     content16: content16, 
                                                                                    content17: content17,
                                                                                    content18: content18,
                                                                                    content19: content19,
                                                                                    content20: content20,
                                                                                     content21: content21


            },              
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   

    });
```

Comment: if you already have backslashed strings in your db you need to remove those slashes first, using stripslashes(), and save them back as it should. Better yeat use parametrized queries to save the hassle of escaping. If you could you should turn magic_quote off in your php.ini. Also, ever heard of loops? :)

Comment: haha, loops would be great... My DB is clean now, do I remove striplashes now?

Comment: Please, please use Prepared Statements! They save you from all sorts of trouble, including your problem here!

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oder to take only one example:

```
UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content21' WHERE element_id = '21')
```

I cannot imagine that this is valid syntax. Maybe you should try

```
UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content21') WHERE element_id = '21'
```

Besides, you are repeating yourself many, many times.

Maybe you better do something like

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 22; $i++) {
    $content = $_POST['content' . $i]; //get posted data
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  //escape string
    $sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content') WHERE element_id = $i";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

(Im not quite sure with the syntax, but you should get the idea)

But even this isn't optimal, as the `mysql_*()` are deprecated in favour of `mysqli_*()` or PDO.

Comment: i think you should start from $i = 1 not 0

Comment: hey, thanks guys. I tried the for loop. I really like the idea but it's not saving to db anymore :(

Comment: @Michel Try again; I didn't obey what I said in the first part in my code in the 2nd part... :-O

Comment: BTW don't forget to do proper error checking; then you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: @glglgl I tried again the for loop and got an ajax error: "the data could not be saved".. snif

Comment: @glgl thanks very much, the for loop actually worked. I don't know it did not work the first time around.. but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a way for all.

`$content1 = stripslashes($_POST['content1']);`

$content1 = mysql_real_escape_string($content1);

Answer (score 2):

All those mysql_* functions are marked as deprecated. So if you or your provider will update the php version on the server, you 'll get a lot of warnings by using the mysql_* functions.

Instead of the mysql_* functions you should use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or mysqli_* functions.

Comment: It's actually the best answer. An obsolete practice is being used, this answer, advice or whatever you want to call it actually fixes all issues and doesn't deal with some black magic involving stripslashes and mysql_real_escape string provided by other "answers". +1 from me

Comment: Hey thanks guys, I'm just not at the level where I can do PDO, but I appreciate your help & knowledge :)